# How to convert a string to xml in C#.net

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

How to convert a string to required xml format in c#.net

If suppose we are having data in string as

```
"XXXX
YYYY
ZZZZ
CCCC"
```

I have required output like based on each and every row should generate with name of

Example

```
<filed1>XXXX></Filed1>
<filed2>YYYY></Filed2>
<filed3>ZZZZ></Filed3>
<filed4>CCCC></Filed4>
```

Comment: You can format a xml file easily using simple string operations..!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to build XML documents in a very elegant way:

```
string data = "XXXX YYYY ZZZZ CCCC";

XDocument doc =
    new XDocument(
        new XElement("root",
            data.Split()
                .Select((item, pos) => new XElement("filed" + (pos + 1), item))
        )
    );

Console.WriteLine(doc);
```

*Output:*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <filed1>XXXX</filed1>
    <filed2>YYYY</filed2>
    <filed3>ZZZZ</filed3>
    <filed4>CCCC</filed4>
</root>
```

Comment: wow. Power of Linq. don't think if i could reproduce what it does though without the example

Comment: this code doesn't compile, what I am missing? I am getting error : System array doesn't contain definition of select..

Comment: @Delashmate `using System.Linq;`